# Twilio alphanumeric sender ID fallback to standard number

Tags: twilio, twilio-javascript

I've got

- a US number
- a well functioning [Messaging Service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services) (`MG...`)
- and a properly configured [Alphanumeric Sender](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services#alphanumeric-sender)

through which I'm sending out programmatic SMSs to various European countries.
Some of these countries apparently don't support Alphanumeric IDs (e.g. [Belgium](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/guidelines/be/sms)).

So, assuming my code looks like this:

```js
import twilio from "twilio";

const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const messagingServiceSid = process.env.TWILIO_MESSAGING_SID;
const twilioClient = twilio(accountSid, authToken);


// https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211 etc
const PhoneRelatedTwilioErrorCodes = [
  21211, 20023, 21217, 21401, 21407, 21421, 21601, 21612, 22102
];

// ... more code

try {
  messageResponse = await twilioClient.messages.create({
    messagingServiceSid,
    to: '123',
    body: 'xyz'
  });
} catch (twexc: any) {
  // ...
}
```

I've got the following questions:

1. Is there a sender ID fallback mechanism / sender pool built into the Node.js SDK?
2. Is there a specific error code for these types of SMS errors? Should I catch this particular exception and try again with the standard sender ID?
3. Any other best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to fall back programmatically. The Messaging Service's [Sender Pool](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/using-messaging-services-with-content-editor#how-to-add-channel-specific-senders-to-a-sender-pool) needs a long code number to fall back to so you'll need to manually add a "Phone Number Sender" alongside your Alpha Sender ID:

[image]

Note for the discerning reader: the order of these senders doesn't really matter. Quoting [the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services#alphanumeric-sender):

> If you add an Alpha Sender to your Twilio Messaging Service, Twilio will select the Alphanumeric Sender ID automatically when you send a message to a supported country, unless you also have a short code number in that same country.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, the fallback order is mentioned [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services#alphanumeric-sender):

> If you add an Alpha Sender to your Twilio Messaging Service, Twilio will select the Alphanumeric Sender ID automatically when you send a message to a supported country, unless you also have a short code number in that same country.

2. see 3.
3. My recommendation would be to avoid errors in the first place by adding a possible sender to all countries, you anticipate to send messages to, the messaging service. I.e. if you cannot message to country X, add a long code number of country X to the messaging service.

Comment: Thanks @IObert. I reckon I'll need to add the long code number to the sender pool in my messaging service settings.